# UWP map layers polygon bugs

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, bing-maps, uwp-maps

I add two shapes on top of each other from two different buttons. When I use the third button to change the stroke size of one of the shape, it also affects the other shape. This is weird because in my code (see `AppBarButton_Click_1`), the adjustment should only alter the FIRST shape that I add. Can someone explain to me what I did wrong?

Link to my code:
[My code (https://pastebin.com/NEVX8SB4)](https://pastebin.com/NEVX8SB4)

Comment: Did you mean to provide some code in this question? Without seeing your code, it's very difficult to provide a helpful answer. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: yes, I put a pastebin url there if you click "My code"

Comment: Thank you for adding a link, but that's only minimally helpful for a couple of reasons. First, links tend to expire so, for the benefit of future users, it's recommended that you put your code _in_ the question. Second, it's unreasonable to expect someone to dig through 150 lines of code to debug your problem for you. If you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), explain the debugging steps you've already taken, and clearly point out where you're stuck, chances are much better that your question will be answered.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to this forum (and programming in general). Thank you you for your input. I will keep that in mind for sure! :)

Comment: No worries; it's understandable! It can be difficult to ask a good question the first time, especially when you're new to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug that should be fixed in the next major Windows update.